# How does embryology provide evidence for evolution?

Tags: evolution, development, embryology

I am not a biology student, I just have a profound fascination and appreciation for biology, and from time to time I like to read and watch videos about it.

I was reading about evolution when I came across different evidence in favor of it, like genealogy, fossil records and embryology. However, it isn't quite clear to me as how embryology provides evidence for evolution.

The way I understand is this - and please correct me, if I am wrong here, - when we observe fetuses of different species, we observe some similarities in the development of those fetuses. But what I am not clear about is how exactly these similarities tell us that through the process of genetic mutation, we obtain new species. What am I missing here? I understand how genetic similarities tell us that we have a common ancestor, and how fossil records show the same.

If you can explain this to me, in words that a layman would understand, then I would be very very thankful. I would also like to know other lines of evidences for evolution in somewhat detail then that would be amazing.

Comment: I think you're forgetting that evolution means common ancestors in addition to mutation and natural selection.

Comment: Similarities of development between species can be interpreted in a roughly similar fashion as similarities of nucleotide sequence. I am confused why you think that a similarity of development could tell you "that through the process of genetic mutation, we obtain new species". Speciation and evolution are rather more than that! I would suggest reading about the field a bit, [here is one review paper](https://evolution-outreach.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1007/s12052-012-0418-x).

Comment: There's an old and mostly discarded notion that [*“ontogeny recapitulates phylogeny”*](https://www.nybg.org/blogs/science-talk/2017/02/a-catchy-phrase-but-is-it-true/), and I think that's what you're expressing here. Just forget about it.

Comment: [This](https://youtu.be/k_9MTZgAhv0?t=464) might interest you

Comment: See [phylotypic stage](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phylotypic_stage).

Comment: Srinidhi, the video in the above link explains the idea of embryo development and evolution, Did you find it helpful? It's expressed in layman's terms.

Comment: When observing fetuses of different species, some similarities in the development of those fetuses are observed.
These similarities suggest that they may share common genes.
Conversely, differences suggest that they may have become a new species through a process of mutation.

Of course, they need to be investigated in detail genetically to see if they are not the result of convergent evolution or adaptive divergence.